# How to add conditions and multi conditions in a multi-step form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add conditional logic so that if `#radio1` is checked then `#step3` will be shown on clicking the next button.

Similarly, if `#radio2` is checked then it will `#step2` will be shown on clicking the next button.

I'm new to Js. So can you help me with the JS code that will result in doing the conditionals?

And please also tell how to add more than 1 conditions... it really helps!

Thanks in advance.

```js
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".next-btn");
let currentSection = 0;

function showSection(sectionIndex) {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".steps");
  sections[currentSection].classList.remove("active-step");
  sections[sectionIndex].classList.add("active-step");
  currentSection = sectionIndex;
}

function nextSection() {
  if (currentSection < 3) {
    showSection(currentSection + 1);
  }
}

function prevSection() {
  if (currentSection > 0) {
    showSection(currentSection - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
.steps{
    display: none;
}

.active-step{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <!-- Step1 -->
    <div class="steps active-step" id="step1">
        <div class="step-title">What's your favourite language?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
                  <label for="html">Python</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
                  <label for="css">Php</label><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" class="next-btn" id="step1-next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Step1.1 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step2">
        <button onclick="prevSection()" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title">How many years of experience you have?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter Year" id="experience-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" class="next-btn" id="step2-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Step1.2 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step3">
        <button onclick="prevSection()" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title">What is your email?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="email" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" class="next-btn" id="step3-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can very easy achieve this with a framework like Vue.JS - it allows you to declaratively specify in your HTML template what should happen depending on different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".next-btn");
let currentSection = 0;

function showSection(sectionIndex) {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".steps");
  // removing all active steps from the DOM
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
     sections[i].classList.remove('active-step');
  }
  // setting up active step to only selected index
  sections[sectionIndex].classList.add("active-step");
  currentSection = sectionIndex;
}

function nextSection(e) {
  // on submit form redirect so preventing it.
    e.preventDefault()
  // getting the index of checked radio
    currentSection = [... document.querySelectorAll("input[name=fav_language]")].findIndex(e=>e.checked)
    showSection(currentSection + 1);
}

function prevSection(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    showSection(0);
}
```

```css
.steps{
    display: none;
}

.active-step{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <!-- Step1 -->
    <div class="steps active-step" id="step1">
        <div class="step-title">What's your favourite language?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="fav_language" value="Python">
                  <label for="html">Python</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="fav_language" value="Php">
                  <label for="css">Php</label>
                   <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="fav_language" value="Python">
                  <label for="html">HTML</label>
                   <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="fav_language" value="Python">
                  <label for="html">CSS</label><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection(event)" class="next-btn" id="step1-next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Step1.1 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step2">
        <button onclick="prevSection(event)" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title">How many years of experience you have?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter Year" id="experience-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" class="next-btn" id="step2-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Step1.2 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step3">
        <button onclick="prevSection(event)" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title">What is your email?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="email" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection(event)" class="next-btn" id="step3-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <!-- Step1.3 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step3">
        <button onclick="prevSection(event)" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title">HTML</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="email" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection(event)" class="next-btn" id="step3-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <!-- Step1.4 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step3">
        <button onclick="prevSection(event)" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title">CSS</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="email" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection(event)" class="next-btn" id="step3-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

check the above snippet, I made the required changes,

Comment: It worked. But I was planning to add 2 more sections to the form. So can you please tell me which part of the code is doing the conditional part? And is it possible to achieve the same with IF ELSE statements?

Comment: doesn't matter you can do it for any number of sections you want, just change the `currentSection < 3` this condition, the conditional rendering part is done `[... document.querySelectorAll("input[name=fav_language]")].findIndex(e=>e.checked)` check the updated answer